# No transactional EntityManager available and exception InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I use spring JPA and custom repository extends JpaRepository, for an very easy function:

```
@Transactional
void functionA(Book Book){
     repositoryA.deleteByBook(Book);
}
```

Then

> javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException

would be thrown, with exception message:

> No transactional EntityManager available

Comment: Please post your Spring configuration.

Comment: post your JPA repositories? are you doing dao on the right repository?

Comment: I updated my question, may it helps

Answer (score 1):

I get the answer now, it is strange:

Because the function should use "public"